# Adding sortable content with Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a page with sortable elements. This is a section of the page code:

```
...
<head>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"</script>
   <script>
        $(function() {
            $( ".sortable" ).sortable();
            $( ".sortable" ).disableSelection();
        });
   </script>
</head>
<div id="screen-page" data-role="page" data-theme="c">
</div>
...
```

I am loading inside "screen-page" HTML content dynamically -with $('#screen-page').append(html)- which is loaded from a database. This content is like:

```
<div data-role="header">Hello</div>
<div id="screenBody" data-role="content" class="sortable">
   (div elements)
</div>
<div id="...">...</div>
```

The problem is: After loading that content, elements inside "screenBody" are not sortable. I think the problem is to add sortable DIV ("screenBody") after loading the page, so the script is not working for the "new" content.

How can I solve the problem?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I added this code:

```
$("#screen-page").on("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {  
    $( ".sortable" ).sortable();
    $( ".sortable" ).disableSelection();
});
```

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use `.on()` to attach event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `$( ".sortable" ).sortable();`  *after* you have loaded your content - right after your `$("#screen-page").append(html);` call.

For example, using `jQuery.get` :

```
$.get('/get-screenpage-content.php', function(html){
   $('#screen-page').append(html);
   $('.sortable').sortable();
   $('.sortable').disableSelection();
});
```

Could you show the code you use to add content to your `#screen-page` div ?